# Judah's sons Er & Onan were killed by God for their sins, and yet, greater sins were maybe made by Judah's brothers Simeon & Levi, for NO punishment?

Tags: genesis, jacob, covenant

In**Genesis 38:7-10** we are told of the deaths of Er and Onan but with little accounting. In **Genesis Ch 34** however we have the whole accounting of Simeon and Levi's despicable actions, which were acted upon by their own volition and against their father (Jacob's) wishes. Their sister Dinah had been defiled by one certain prince by the name of Shechem, of the land of the same name, but who later wanted to do the honorable thing and enter into marriage with Dinah and even agreed to become circumcised and even convinced all of his male compatriots to do the same, in order for both sets of people to be able to live together in harmony with each other, even share and share alike. Simeon and Levi had even been party to this agreement, but then reneged in the worst possible way, by not only killing all of Shechem's city's males, including Shechem and his father Hamor, but then went on to loot same city, and then they get away 'Scot-Free'. Really!!

Comment: I am not sure there is any answer to this question as it essentially asks to rank the punishments for various sins - that is a divine judgement for God alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in Judah's case was lineage, a  crucial theme in Genesis. Er's sin is not specified but Onan's is: he refused to conceive a child with Tamar and thus carry on Judah's lineage. (Incidentally an ancient tradition quoted by the medieval sage Rashi tells us that Er also refused to conceive a child with Tamar, because he felt her pregnancy would spoil her beauty. - Yebamot 34b.) For Jews the refusal to carry on Judah's lineage would mean that King David and his descendants would not have been born; indeed the tribe and entire nation of Judah would be cut off. For Christians it means that Jesus would never have been born. In addition, the refusal to have children constituted a rebellion against the first blessing/commandment given by God to human beings: "Be fruitful and multiply."

This in no way excuses Simeon and Levi. But they and their descendants were indeed punished harshly, though not immediately. Jacob's final words to them were a curse:

Genesis 49:5-7 NABRE

> <sup>**5**</sup> Simeon and Levi, brothers indeed, weapons of violence are their knives. <sup>**6**</sup> Let not my person enter their council, or my honor be joined with their company; For in their fury they killed men, at their whim they maimed oxen. <sup>**7**</sup> Cursed be their fury so fierce, and their rage so cruel! I will scatter them in Jacob, disperse them throughout Israel.

Historically, Levi's tribe hand no land of its own, and Simeon's land was absorbed into Judah.

**Conclusion**: Er and Onan's punishment shows the importance of the duty to carry on the lineage of the chosen people and tribe. Although as individuals they were punished more harshly than Levi and Simeon, their ancestral line was blessed  and carried on through the bravery of Tamar. Simeon and Levi received their father's curse at the end of his life. From the Bible's viewpoint this was a fate worse than death.

Comment: Well, I've got to hand it to you. I find this to be a good, if not somewhat excellent answer. It therefore behooves me to give out the proverbial upvote. Even if you, yourself, find it difficult to *openly* reciprocate, whether it be by positive vote (if warranted), or just a mere thanks in "Comment", I, myself, should be (and I always try to be *open*) giving credit when credit is shown to be due, especially, if in answer to my own Q. I, myself, *openly* comment (much to other's "chagrin") even when I downvote, as per the *due* requisites of the **BH** advisory board, but I rarely downvote.

Comment: I too make sure to explain my downvotes. With upvotes I usually comment only when I have something to add. The tour advises us [not to comment with "thanks"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) but I will try to give you feedback, whether positive or negative, in the future.

Comment: FYI I noticed that the SE system "corrects" numerous upvotes given to a particular user by another user during a short period of time. I upvoted several of your posts recently as a result my taking a look at some of them... I hope they were not "corrected."

Comment: Not as yet, but I too was made aware of that policy when I did the same thing for another user. Can't remember the exact reasoning though.

Comment: There's just one problem - if this were merely about lineage Reuben was the firstborn and the lineage would continue through the other 11 brothers. Instead, the more likely explanation is that the concern was for the widow - Tamar. Without a son, she would be unable to own property and there was no one to take care of her economic future in her old age. Because Tamar was not a virgin, she otherwise would have been unable to re-marry. Levirate marriage practice is about caring for the marginalized within the social framework of the time, not ensuring lineage.

Comment: The remaining son also could have married someone other than Tamar to continue the lineage.

Comment: Levirite marriage was not instituted yet at this time, although it may have been a custom. That is one reason I see the main issue as being lineage. About Reuben's position, the pattern in Genesis was for first-born sons to be passed over - as with Cain and Esau. The remaining son apparently did have children (1 chr 4) but Tamar's sons were the ones with providential significance... reversing the positions of Cain/Abel or Esau/Jacob while still in the womb.

Comment: also... as a widow she would not be forbidden to remarry. She would be less desirable than a maiden but nothing prohibited her.

Answer (score 0):

Their offence and their punishment is covered in Genesis ch49 vv5-7. The punshment is "I will divide them in Jacob and scatter them in Israel". Simeon ends up being a small remnant, almost absorbed into the tribe of Judah (Joshua ch19 v9), and not even mentioned in the tribal list of Deuteronomy ch33. Levi has an honoured status later (for services rendered), but they are still "scattered".

Comment: So they didn't exactly get away "scott-free" in the end , although the tribe of Levi get's an honored status at a later date, even though scattered. This still doesn't explain however, why the two brothers were in effect minimally punished, whereas Er and Onan received the ultimate punishment and for *possibly* lessor chrime's.

Comment: Unfortunately God rarely chooses to justify his decisions, as Job discovered. I think we've got as far as we can.

Comment: Well, that's as maybe, but I wonder whether we may have a case of ... *the sins of the fathers may be delivered on the sons* .. Judah, the father of Er & Onan,  apparently was the "brotherhood" ring leader, who suggested that Joseph be sold to the Midianites, unbeknownst to Rueben - firstborn of the 4 brethren, to Jacob & Leah, that included Simeon, Levi and Judah - who had sought to free Joseph from the pit that all the brothers, (by whichever wife/maidservant of Jacob's), had thrown him into, but who then, having little other choice, went along with deceiving their father of Joseph's demise.

Comment: Then, as if that wasn't enough, Judah then later committed the same sin that befell Shechem, which resulted in the births of Er & Onan.